# The return value of "filter" must be used

Tags: angular, sonarqube

please see below code

```
let statusFilter;
this.columnList.filter(obj => {
  if(obj.attributeName === gridStaticColumns.licenseStatus && obj.attributeDataType === AttributeDataTypes.staticValueList){
    statusFilter = true;
  }
})
```

We are using sonarqube as our code quality and code coverage tool. So, for the above block of code it reported an issue that the return value of filter must be used. I didn't understood what it is mentioning here and what to change. Can some one please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array with items that match the filter criteria. A good use of the `filter` method is to assign the resulted array to a variable:

```
const result = this.columnList.filter(/* ... */);
```

In your case, you can get away with [using `some` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const statusFilter = this.columnList.some(obj => obj.attributeName === gridStaticColumns.licenseStatus && obj.attributeDataType === AttributeDataTypes.staticValueList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#filter` isn't synonymous with `Array#forEach`. The former is used to remove elements from array based on a condition. And importantly it doesn't change the array in-place. It returns a new array.

In your case, it seems you'd want to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let statusFilter = this.columnList.some(obj => 
  obj.attributeName === gridStaticColumns.licenseStatus && 
  obj.attributeDataType === AttributeDataTypes.staticValueList
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the filter function will iterate through all the values of `columnList` and filter out the values which meets the condition written inside it. As mentioned, `filter` function will expect a boolean value to be returned from the condition inside of it. You can do below to fix your problem.

Change the filter code to one of these

1.

```
this.columnList.filter(obj => 
  (obj.attributeName === gridStaticColumns.licenseStatus && obj.attributeDataType === AttributeDataTypes.staticValueList));
```

2. 

```
this.columnList.filter(obj => {
  if(obj.attributeName === gridStaticColumns.licenseStatus && obj.attributeDataType === AttributeDataTypes.staticValueList) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
});
```

Then the filter will return array of items which satisfied the condition. You may have to assign them to a variable and check its length to determine the value for `statusFilter`.